# Prrogrammatically selecting links from a table

Tags: automated-tests, salesforce, qtp, hp-uft

I am using UFT to test Salesforce. The Acme Corp. account has 2 contacts: "James Bean" and "Marsha Smith". but it can have more contacts. I am trying to programmatically select the  links for these contacts and click on them. I wrote this code to get all the links on that  page

```
Dim oDesc
Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc("micclass").value = "Link"

'Find all the Links
Set obj = Browser("Contacts | Salesforce").Page("Contacts | Salesforce").ChildObjects(oDesc)
```

[image]

The problem is when I loop trough obj, there is no way to programmatically distinguish the 2 Contacts links from the other links on the Menus. They all have the same class.

How can I access the table and its contents programmatically from an Action?

I attached screenshots of the contacts object and the HTML table of the links.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the links you're interested in are all nested inside a table which you know how to identify, you can call `ChildObjects` on the `WebTable` rather than on the `Page`.

See [this blog post](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/10/07/understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-hp-unified-functional-testing-uft/#Element).

Comment: The following code works but ObjChildItem.Click() gets executed only the first time.  Only Jim Bean's contact profile is displayed, not Marsha Smith's.

For i = 2 to rowCount
           
       Set ObjChildItem = obj(0).ChildItem(i,3,"Link", 0)
        
         ObjChildItem.Click()
        
           RunAction "ValidateContactProperties", oneIteration
             
        End  If
    Next

Comment: @Burak, I've answered this in the [question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368570), you need to call `ChildObjects` again after each `Click`.